# Angular Controllers as vm inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I want to use the vm [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285597/angularjs-why-use-controller-as-vm) of controllers writing. The problem is that I faced with is inheritance, for example lets assume I have the following:

**Base Controller:**

```
  angular.module('app')
    .controller('BaseCtrl', BaseCtrl);

  function BaseCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm._privateVar = 1;
  }

  BaseCtrl.prototype.foo= function() {
    console.log('foo')
  };
```

**Child Controller:**

```
  angular.module('app')
    .controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);

  function ChildCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
  }

  ChildCtrl.prototype.goo= function() {
    console.log('goo')
  };
```

**Note:**
I have an access to injection only within the ChildCtrl function:

```
function ChildCtrl(/*I can inject here only*/) {
    var vm = this;
}
```

Also, The BaseCtrl is not a global class/function/object. 
Is there is any whay to inject the controller service outside of the controller function?

How should I make `ChildCtrl` inherit form `BaseCtrl`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I made the following,

```
  //get the injector.
  var injector = angular.injector(['app']);

  //get the service.
  var $controller = injector.get('$controller');
  var BaseCtrl = $controller('BaseCtrl');

  angular.module('app')
    .controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);

  function ChildCtrl() {
     var vm = this;
     BaseCtrl.call(this);
  }

  ChildCtrl.prototype = Object.create(BaseCtrl);
```

As you can see I have injected the `$controller` service got the BaseCtrl with it.

I know this is ugly as hell and I will glad to hear better suggestions;

Answer (score 0):

in your child controller you can do:

```
function ChildCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  BaseCtrl.call(this);
}

ChildCtrl.prototype = Object.create(BaseCtrl);
```

With this approach BaseCtrl would need to be global. You could get similar code reuse with a mixin and it wouldn't use a global but you won't get anything off of the base prototype. e.g.:

```
var BaseCtrlMixinService = function() {
  this.myValue = 123;
  this.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(this.myValue);
  }
}

angular.module('app').service('baseCtrlMixin', BaseCtrlMixinService);


function ChildCtrl(baseCtrlMixin) {
  var vm = this;
  angular.extend(this, baseCtrlMixin);
}

angular.module('app').controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);
```

Comment: from where I will get the BaseCtrl? it is in separate script file and not globally set(also see the note in the question).

Comment: yeah unfortunately it's gotta be global

Comment: Bad news :(
is there any way to inject it with the angular (the only that is global) object?

Comment: nope. You could use a third party module system to avoid a global. Or just use a mixin instead of inheritance

Comment: Can you give an example of mixins?

Comment: I need the prototype :(, there must be a hack!