# Set context scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I have my variables bound to `this` in my controller, and in my route designation I use `controllerAs: 'game'`. This allows me to include them in my HTML with `{{game.var}}`. Sometimes, I bind objects that I want to display, but this forces me to write repeatedly `{{game.object.a}}`, `{{game.object.b}}`, `{{game.object.c}}`.

In a previous project using Meteor, I could set the data context with the `with` keyword.

```
{{#with object}}
  {{a}}
  {{b}}
{{/with}}
```

but I don't see a similar feature to this in Angular. The closest I've been able to make work is adding the attribute `ng-repeat="object in [game.object]"`. This works, but it isn't very semantic. This also causes me to get a quick flash of a second element when `game.object` changes, as the new one loads before the first one is erased.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular intentionally uses this context scope to avoid confusion between parent and child scopes. If you're not using child scopes, you can skip the controller as syntax entirely and just bind everything to `$scope` in your model, which turns `game.a` and `game.b` to just `a` and `b` in your view.

If you are using child scopes, you can still skip controllerAs, but then it  becomes confusing what controller a given model in the view belongs to. There's no `with` or `using` syntax, so you need to declare the bound scope `game.a`, `childGame.a` everywhere you refer to these models, which might be overly verbose but is at least clear.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285597/angularjs-why-use-controller-as-vm), as well.

Regarding the flash issue, I would avoid using ng-repeat for semantic purposes. It's primary use case is to display an array of similarly structured data.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the styleguide provided at https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/ where it discourages binding directly to `$scope`. I am starting to think that every situation where I might prefer this `with` or `using` syntax, I should probably be inserting a directive instead, which would mitigate the problem entirely.

Comment: Yes, I think this is wise. Directives, when used correctly, have the added benefit of modularizing your view and keeping data encapsulated.

Comment: Alright, I will move in that direction. Thank you for your thoughts